# Implementing a backend-less auth mechansim

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, aws-api-gateway

I would like to implement an SPA which bounces the user to a login page, if not already logged in. It would then able to make a call to an API (not necessarily an API Gateway) hosted within an AWS VPC.

As I currently understand it, this would involve a front-end framework library authenticating the user via OAuth 2.0. It would then need to retrieve a token (allowed because of the auth validation) to call an API Gateway which provides access to the API hosted within the VPC.

Given this concept, is this architecture possible without the use of a Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

- If you are willing to use API Gateway in front of your API:

Yes, this architecture is possible without using a Lambda. API Gateway has integration with AWS Cognito User Pools for authorizing requests. You can find the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html) on how to set this up.

- If you don't have an AWS API gateway in front of your API:

In this case you will have to implement one of the [authentication and authorization flows](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/which-oauth-2-0-flow-should-i-use) provided by OAuth 2.0 standard. In this case, whether you would want to use a Lambda or not, is up to you and your back-end architecture.